# Inconsistent python import_module behavior

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm experiencing some strange and inconsistent behavior of Python3's `importlib.import_module` function.  I am wondering 1) if anyone else has experienced this and 2) best ways to remedy.  If relevant, I am using Python 3.5.3 in a Docker container based on Debian(stretch).

The background is that I have a framework where I allow developers to write small bits of customized code.  As a very basic check, my script uses `importlib.import_module` to "ingest" the code; syntax errors, etc. would be raised if there were very obvious problems with their code.

I create a staging directory and copy their python file into that folder.  I then run (from the same directory as `BASE_DIR` below):

```
# if base is /foo, and module_path is at /foo/bar/xyz.py
# this gives bar/xyz.py
module_path_relative_to_base = os.path.relpath(
    module_path, 
    start=BASE_DIR    
)
# makes "bar/xyz.py" into "bar.xyz" 
module_dot_path = module_path_relative_to_base.replace('/', '.')[:-3]

# import that module:
mod = import_module(module_dot_path)
```

*Most* of the time (say, 80% of the time) this works.  However, sometimes I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "workflow_ingestion/ingest_workflow.py", line 700, in <module>
    handler_name_list = check_handlers(staging_dir)
  File "workflow_ingestion/ingest_workflow.py", line 495, in check_handlers
    inspect_handler_module(module_path, 'add_to_context', 2)    
  File "workflow_ingestion/ingest_workflow.py", line 432, in inspect_handler_module
    mod = import_module(module_dot_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'workflow_ingestion.staging.20190130.file_chooser_handler'
```

which would seemingly indicate that the file `workflow_ingestion/staging/20190130/file_chooser_handler.py` was not there.  That is not the case-- when I list the directory following this error, the file is definitely there.

HOWEVER, the strange thing is that if I put a `print` statement in front of that call to `importlib.import_module`, it ALWAYS works!  As soon as I remove the `print` call, the error shows up again (!!).

I am wondering if this is some strange bug(?) where the previous file copy (using python's `shutil.copy2`) has not fully "registered" with the filesystem/OS, or with with python's interaction with those?  Filesystems/OS is way out of my wheelhouse, so I have no idea if that could be the source.

My temporary solution is to leave that print statement, or add a `time.sleep` call, which has also proven "effective", as this is not a time-sensitive process.  Any other ideas?  I'm OK with that hack, but it's just very strange to me!

Comment: Does module_dot_path exist when the interpreter is launched? If not, you may want to call invalidate_caches() as described in the doc: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module